# Javascript video won't load in my small widget app

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I'm trying to build out a pretty basic widget system that renders some content and videos depending on the widget's ID. I thought I had a pretty solid method of doing this until I've run into a bug that is preventing my videos from loading.

I'd like to know if 1) the method I'm using is an ideal approach and 2) if the bug I'm experiencing is something on my end that can be fixed. Here's how I have it setup.

You place the following code on your website where you want the widget to render:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://testing.womensforum.com/widgets/example.js"></script>
    <div id="wf_widget"></div>
    <script>Widget.Load('098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6', 'wf_widget');</script>
```

That'll call the JS code below, which sends an AJAX request to the server asking for the HTML code that it should render. Once I have that, I insert a blank iframe into the div element (wf_widget) which I use to write the HTML code I got from the server into the iframes document.

```
    var host   = 'http://testing.womensforum.com/widgets/example.php';
    var Widget = {
        Load: function(widget_hash, element_id) {
            var http = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");

            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    var html = http.responseText;
                    var iframe = "<iframe allowtransparency=\"false\" style=\"border: 1px solid #8c8b8b; z-index:10;\" width=\"300\" height=\"600\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>";

                    var div = document.getElementById(element_id);
                    div.innerHTML = iframe;

                    var frame = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
                    var doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document || frame.contentWindow.window.document;

                    doc.write(html);
                }
            }

            http.open("POST", host, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.send("widget_hash=" + encodeURIComponent(widget_hash));
        }
    };
```

This seems to work really well up until I tried loading a video. To see a live example, you can go here:
http://testing.womensforum.com/widgets/example.html

You'll notice that the video player loads, but no video is playing. But if you check out the HTML that the JS code is getting here:
http://testing.womensforum.com/widgets/example.php

You see that the video is loading just fine, it's only when I pipe that HTML code through our JS that it stops working.

Can anyone give any insight as to what the issue is and if there is a better approach for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this reason??  With Ajax - it has cross-domain policy where ajax will function/operate given that the file or callback is within the same domain of server.  If  you are trying to achieve the cross-domain approach, then explore different avenue, not ajax - if I am correct.